# Does a ranged weapon's size affect the weapon's range?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack, creature-size

I want to introduce my group to a Large creature that uses a bow. Does this Large creature's Large bow have a longer range than the typical bow?

Does an official rule cover this, or must I make a house rule?

Comment: [This question isn't a duplicate, but if nothing else comes up linked is the identical question for *3.5e.*](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87644/8610)

Comment: If you're looking for a "fair" rule on how to modify range, maybe reference the [Space, Reach, & Threatened Area Templates](vhttp://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates), where the *Typical Height/Lenght* column will allow you to compare size categories in a relevant matter. For example, a large creature is about twice as big as a medium one, so their range could be twice as high. Though if you create a Colossal enemy (16 times as large as a medium character), they could snipe your group from quite a distance - long before you could do anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Pathfinder, ranged weapon range is not affected by weapon size. While it is difficult to conclusively confirm this, a search of the [Equipment section in the core rulebook](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/equipment.html) reveals that the section on weapon size makes no statements regarding adjusting range or range increments.

As Hey I Can Chan mentioned, this was a rule in D&D 3.0 (and since Pathfinder is based on 3.5, it was never a part of Pathfinder).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Anyway, would you make a rule for this specific situation ?

Comment: @Binochio If you want to make a house-rule to add this back in, check out the link in Hey I Can Chan's comment to your question above. In D&D3.0, increasing or decreasing the size of a weapon changed its range increment by 25% for each size change away from medium.